# How to restore Firefox session from previous.jsonlz4?

Tags: firefox

I accidently opened a new Firefox window, and after that closed main window with all 600 tabs, and newly opened one. When I opened Firefox next time - all tabs gone.

Luckily I managed to copy sessionstore-backups from profile folder. With https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html I verified that previous.jsonlz4 and/or recovery.jsonlz4 contains all of them, but I couldn't restore them into Firefox.

The only thing that worked is moving upgrade.jsonlz4-$date to profile's sessionstore.jsonlz4, but this file contains only a month old session, and previous or recovery doesn't work. Some people suggested to crash Firefox (I did that with killall -9 firefox-esr) and trigger session restore from history menu, but such button does not appear.

How can I restore session from  previous.jsonlz4 / recovery.jsonlz4?
Or atleast just open all parsed links from https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html with one click?

And is there any config flag to forbid firefox to open new regular windows (not private)? To prevent this from happening again.

Firefox ESR (115.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it.
Here's the steps:

1. Use [Scrounger](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html) to process previous.jsonlz4, save it as sessionstore.js format
2. Use [mozlz4](https://github.com/jusw85/mozlz4) to compress sessionstore.js (example CLI prompt: mozlz4 --compress sessionstore(previous_jsonlz4).json > sessionstore.jsonlz4)
3. Close Firefox
4. Move sessionstore-backups and empty sessionstore.jsonlz4 out of profile folder
5. Copy compressed sessionstore.jsonlz4 into profile folder
6. Open Firefox, open History menu, and now recently closed windows should be accessible and your previous closed window should be there.